# How to reverse direction of plt.barh?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Normally plt.barh creates a horizontal bar plot with bars aligned to their left edge and pointing to the right.

How can I change this so the bars will be aligned to their right edges and pointing left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful if you provided some example of data that you are trying to plot.

If you data is negative, then the bars would naturally point to the left, with the 0 value at the right edge of the plot.

```
data = np.random.random(size=(5,))
data2 = data * -1
plt.figure()
plt.barh(y=range(5),width=data2)
```

[image]

If you want to keep your values positive, but have them point to the left, then the easiest would probably be to simply reverse the direction of the xaxis:

```
plt.figure()
plt.barh(y=range(5),width=data)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, it was exactly what I was looking for - positive values pointing left.

Comment: Can I move  ylabels the same way?

Comment: use [ax.yaxis.tick_right()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.YAxis.tick_right.html?highlight=tick_right#matplotlib-axis-yaxis-tick-right)